window.moveBy() does not work for the window which is in the same directory
I was trying to move a window using window.moveTo(), but I get
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "moveBy" on cross-origin object
error when I run this code. I moved the HTML file of the popup window to the same directory, but it didn't work...
Any solutions? Thanks
This is the entire code of the file:
var screenwidth = window.screen.width;
var ww = 100;
var a = window.open('./subwindow.html', 'window', 'top=100,left=100,width=300,height=400');

function movewindow() {
    while (ww < screenwidth) {
        a.window.moveBy(1, 0);
        ww += 1;
        if (ww == screenwidth) {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (ww > 0) {
        a.window.moveBy(-1, 0);
        ww -= 1;
        if (ww == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

setInterval("movewindow()", 1000);

I expected the popup to move until the right edge of the screen and go back to the left side of it. It didn't move however, and the error above occurred.

Are you working with file protocol?

What is file protocol? I apologize for my ignorance...

I run this code in local file, is it the problem?

Yes, that is the problem - if by "local" you mean file:/// protocol (look at the address bar in your browser)

Yes, this file's address is like that... Doesn't moveBy work in file protocol?

moveBy works on the same page, but not on a cross-origin object, as which the opened window is treated with file protocol. You'll need to instal a local server to resolve this issue (i.e. you need http(s) protocol to access other files).
